# Unity3D How to copy object to paste at same position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I want to copy object and paste at same position by using Ctrl+c Barn1_Door_A at the center of map like this image.

[image]

when I paste by Ctrl+v the object is out of map like this image.

[image]

The component value of object is same value but why it paste out of map. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: ctrl + D? (duplicate). I think that duplicates the prefab in the same hierarchy of the source prefab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight Barn1_Door_A and press Ctrl+d. It should duplicate the gameobject in the same location.

The only reason I can think of why your object isn't located in the same spot as the other one is the it is being made in a different place in the hierarchy (i.e not as a child of LockedBuildings)